# mysql 4.1.22 in vagrant ubuntu precise 64

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I need a vagrant machine for developing unluckily w/ mysql 4.1.22.

Would you recommend any old packages from older ubunuts, or is it better to compile mysql on my own in ubuntu 12.04.

Or is the better solution even to install an old ubuntu in virtual box?

Best!

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to use older version of ubuntu you should compile packages from source code, Why you really want to install older version of ubuntu? If it is due to performance  issue try lxde or lfce